# I am not able to delete value from database?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am not able to delete value from database my database has 4 columns student name, student id number,student mobile number and father's name. I wanted to delete student's record by entering students' id number.

```
def deleting (self):
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="**",    # your host, usually localhost
                 user="**",         # your username
                 passwd="***",  
                 db="idk")        # name of the data base
    cursor = db.cursor()
    student_ID=self.student_ID.get()
    print(student_ID)
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM Student_details WHERE student_ID=%s",(student_ID,))
    db.commit()
    db.close()
    self.message['text'] = 'Record {} deleted'.format(student_ID)
```

It is printing student id which says it is receiving value but not able to delete the record.

Comment: Well what is wrong with your code?  Does nothing get deleted, the wrong records get deleted, something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen nothing gets deleted

Comment: is student_ID a string? if yes, in the where condition it should say - student_ID='%s'

Comment: @KevinMangold Database drivers do not need, nor do they want a semi-colon. That's the default statement delimiter in interactive shells, but this driver is not an interactive shell. the end of the string is the end of the statement.

Comment: @rhn89, You do not want '%s'. %s represents a parameter and the driver is smart enough to recognize that the actual parameter being passed is a string.